# Suppress the legend in a ggplot2/qplot density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I've looked through the description and the book on **ggplot2** and cannot find a simple way of eliminating the legend in a simple density plot with a filled color.

Here is what I've tried with a simple sequence of 1000 numbers (plotseries) that had about 200
NA in the first 200 spots.

```
qplot(plotseries,geom="density",fill="red",na.rm=TRUE,show_guide=FALSE)

qplot(plotseries,geom="density",fill="red",na.rm=TRUE,legend.position="none")
```

I looked at the online **ggplot2** doc and could not find anything there either....

Comment: Maybe you mean to do `fill = I("red")` so no legend is created?

Comment: @aosmith is correct: `I` is required here. Try e.g. fill='green' and you'll see that the fill colour is the same.

Comment: As a side note, if you plan to use ggplot further, it is commonly advised to switch to `ggplot` call instead of `qplot` since the latter obscures the philosophy of the plotting language for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I do intend on using ggplot but for the moment I just needed the simplicity of qplot until I get through the ggplot2 book and experiment with it.

Comment: And if I want to use a variable for the color, how do I continue to suppress the legend?  Do I have to go to ggplot instead?

Comment: You can add `+ guides(fill = FALSE)` after your `qplot` code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use the normal qplot command and then add  + theme(legend.position = "none") to your code, it will remove the legend. So, your code will look as follows:

```
qplot(plotseries,geom="density",fill="red",na.rm=TRUE) + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Usually such things work just as they would work in the ggplot2 command.